# transversality for reducible holomorphic curve

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, 4-manifolds

Let $(X, \omega)$ be a  strong symplectic cobordism between nondegenerate contact manifolds $(Y_+, \lambda_+)$ and  $(Y_-, \lambda_-)$. Let $\overline{X}$ be usual symplectization completion of $X$ and $J$ be almost complex structure on $\overline{X}$ satisfying the usual conditions.

Fix Reeb orbits sets $\alpha_+$ and $\alpha_-$ on   $(Y_+, \lambda_+)$ and  $(Y_-, \lambda_-)$ respectively. Let $\Sigma$ be a connected Riemann surface with punctures. Let $\mathcal{M}_J(\alpha_+, \alpha_-, A)$ be  moduli space of all somewhere injective holomorphic curves $u:\Sigma \to \overline{X}$ which have positive end at $\alpha_+$ and negative end at $\alpha_-$ and  $[u]=A$. For generic $J$, it is well known that  $\mathcal{M}_J(\alpha_+, \alpha_-, A)$ is a smooth manifold with dimensional $ind D_u$.

> My question: Now if I allow $\Sigma= \coprod \Sigma_i$ to be disconnected, but I add one more constraint that $u(\Sigma_i) \cap u(\Sigma_j)=\emptyset$  if $i \ne j$.  Is the moduli space still a manifold with dimension $ind D_u= \sum_i D_{u \vert_{\Sigma_i}}$?

Comment: Do you know how the standard proof for somewhere injective curves goes? This question is an exercise if you do. I can explain more if you would like.

Comment: I read the proof for somewhere injective curves. The point is to show that the deformation operator $D_u: \Gamma(u^*TX) \to \Gamma(\overline{Hom}(T\Sigma, u^*TX))$ (some sobolev space) is subjective.  If $\Sigma$ is disconnected,  it seems that everything can be spited into direct sum and we just need to copy the original argument directly.  I wonder if I'm missing anything? If you don't mind, could you give me more explanation. Thanks.

Comment: What you say is correct. In particular, the way I would say it is that your condition that the curve is somwhere injective on each component and the images of components are disjoint is stronger than necessary: you only need the total curve (with disconnected domain) to be somewhere injective. Take a look at Chapter 7 of Wendl's lecture notes, for instance https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.01009
Also take a look at McDuff-Salamon for closed curves -- their discussion generalizes completely and contains all the ideas.

Comment: Here's the exercise: prove the result under the weaker condition that for $i \ne j$, $u(\Sigma_i)$ and $u(\Sigma_j)$ are not contained one in the other.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much  for your detailed explanation.